# htaccess redirect all subdomains + www to domain with cname, vhosts and htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rather simple problem for someone who knows, I just cant find the answer that I need. I have moved to vps and try to configure vm by myself. I need redirects:

1. domain.com - default
2. www.domain.com -> domain.com
3. *.domain.com -> domain.com

I`ve already done .htaccess for www -> non-www, so I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Added A and CNAME:

- www - @
- * - @

Added virtualhost

- ServerAlias www.domain.com *.domain.com

Am I doing right (CNAME, vhost, .htaccess) or it can me done simplier?

Can you please help me redirect *.domain.com -> domain.com (guess in .htaccess) ?

Comment: what are the sub domains you want to redirect ? OR you want to redirect all sub domains

Comment: all subdomains. eg wwww2.domain.com / asda.domain.com -> all redirect to domain.com (without www)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> redirect *.domain.com -> domain.com

Just change your rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Can this work with multi-level subdomains? this.sorta.domain.com?

Comment: For that keep first condition as: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+?\.(domain\.com)$ [NC]`

Comment: @Leo: Post a new question with all details and I will attend.

Answer (score 4):

Set your server alias to *.domain.com in your Apache config, below your server name:

```
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias *.domain.com
```

Everything to non-www:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/  [L,R]
```

Everything to www:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$   [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/  [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

create .htaccess and paste this

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$   [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/  [L,R]
```